# keeping the main screen greyed out while loading gif

Tags: html, css

I am displaying a progress bar(loading gif) while my screen loads.

my css entries are as below

```
.hiddenDiv {
    display: none;

}

.visibleDiv {
    display: none;
}
.hiddenStyle {
    cursor: wait;
    z-index: 99999;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    filter: alpha(opacity=80);
}

.busyStyle {
        position: absolute;
        top: 300px;
        left: 580px;
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align: middle;
        font-family: arial, helvetica, verdana, sans - serif;
        color: red;
        font-size: 16px;
        font-weight: bold;

}
```

when I include  `background-color: white;` in hiddenStyle, then the main screen behind is replaced by a white background while the page is loading.

If I remove that entry, then the progress bar is displayed with main screen behind.

I would like to grey out the main screen behind while the progress bar is displayed. How do I achieve this by changing CSS entries ?

**Achieved this** by changing CSS entries as

```
.visibleDiv {
    z-index: 99999;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
    opacity: 0.6;
    background-color: white;

}
```

**in JS**

```
document.getElementById('mask').className = 'visibleDiv';
```

**so opacity did the trick**

Comment: Can you make a fiddle of this along with the HTML code?

Comment: are you running js/jQuery as well or just css?

Comment: Hi Liam, I am using js(edited my question with js and jsp code)

Comment: Hi Rishabh, am not sure on the fiddle thing ?

Comment: Which is the `div` that contains loader? Just increase the `z-index` of that `div`

Comment: Hi Rishabh, what value do you suggest me to increase ?

Comment: Rishab, I tried increasing the value from 99999 to 999999, but it did not work

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully, this can help as I have it implemented and working on a website:

**HTML**

```
<div id="divLoading">
    <div class="page-center">
        <div class="loadingBox">
            <div class="centered">
                Loading...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Put this anywhere on your page.

**CSS**

```
#divLoading {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%; height: 100%;
    background-color: #666666;
    z-index: 30001;
    opacity: .9;
    filter: alpha(opacity=90);
    display: none;
}

.page-center {
    display: inline;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    position: relative;
}

.loadingBox {
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 20px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -150px;
  margin-left: -150px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: white;
}

.centered {
    text-align: center;
}
```

And when you call the said loading method (the one which shows the progress bar) also call this:

```
$("#divLoading").show();
```

It will show a div in front of everything else. When the progress is done, call:

```
$("#divLoading").hide();
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the response, but this implementation is completely greying out the background, I would like to fade out the background but still like to see the background screen while progress bar is displayed

Comment: I think I don't understand exactly what you mean but, what if you change `opacity: .9;` to `opacity: .5;`, for example? It becomes less opaque and allows the user to see better what's on the background. As another option, you can place your progress bar inside the `loadingDiv` and it would then show clearly as opposed to the background

Answer (score 0):

You can have following set at the loading time of document:

```
<html><body>
<script>
document.body.style.backgroundColor='gray';
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Once your progress is loaded you can reset the body color:

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor='#fff';
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the response, but this would grey out my background completely